# Is there a LWE based public-key encryption scheme which is CCA1-secure?

Tags: public-key, lattice-crypto, cca1

Is there a lattice based PKE which is IND-CCA1 secure? Actually I am only familiar with LWE and SIS. So I want to know that what the IND-CCA1-secure LWE based PKE scheme looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can see Micciancio's [annotated bibliography](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/LatticeLinks/CCA.html) for some relevant papers (including generic transformations from CPA security to CCA security in the random oracle model). If you want to see "actual" schemes which are CCA1 secure, [Kyber](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/index.shtml) is a CCA2-secure KEM with security based on a variant of LWE over "Module Lattices", which can be viewed as a slight generalization of R-LWE.